# Batch File modify text file for NSIS installer

Tags: batch-file, nsis

As part of an NSIS script builder I have a list of filenames that are currently in a file called files.txt.  An example of the content is below...

```
c:\myfolder\assets\startup.xml
c:\myfolder\assets\begin.exe
c:\myfolder\assets\begin.swf
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\help.pdf
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\license.rtf
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\piano.swf
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\numbers.swf
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item1.jpg
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item2.jpg
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section4\resource1\item7.jpg
c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section4\resource1\item8.jpg
```

I am trying to process this list of files using a batch file so that they end up looking like this...

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\startup.xml"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\begin.exe"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\begin.swf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\assets\text"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\help.pdf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\assets\text"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\license.rtf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\assets\swf"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\piano.swf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\assets\swf"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\numbers.swf"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\section1\resource1"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item1.jpg"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\section1\resource1"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item2.jpg"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\section4\resource1"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section4\resource1\item7.jpg"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resources\section4\resource1"
File "c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section4\resource1\item8.jpg"
```

I have tried a few things but haven't really been able to find a solution.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so going on from Aacini's post I have modified the batch file slightly as below...

```
dir "c:\n\assets" /b /s > "c:\n\original.txt"
type "c:\n\original.txt" | findstr \. > "c:\n\filelist.txt"
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET PATH=C:\n
set INSTDIR="c:\n\assets\"
( for /F "delims=" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
     set "filePath=%%~DPa"
     set "outPath=!filePath:%INSTDIR%=!"
     if defined outPath set "outPath=\!outPath:~0,-1!"
     echo SetOutPath "$INSTDIR!outPath!"
     echo File "%%a"
  )
) > "c:\n\result.txt"
REM move /Y c:\result.txt files.txt
```

I made a couple of changes mainly with quotes to allow spaces to be used in the path names, and I also set the path to allow everything to work correctly when being called from NSIS.  The problem I am facing now is that instead of....

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\assets"
File "c:\my folder\assets\startup.xml"
```

I get....

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\c:\my folder\assets"
File "c:\my folder\assets\startup.xml"
```

I imaging it is a real easy fix to resolve but I am pulling my hair out trying to change it!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

NSIS can include a directory tree with `File /r "c:\myfolder\"` etc but if you really want to parse a text file you can try something like this:

```
;create a file list for this example
!delfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt"
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\begin.swf$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\help.pdf$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\text\license.rtf$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\piano.swf$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\assets\swf\numbers.swf$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item1.jpg$\n
!appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\resources\section1\resource1\item2.jpg$\n

outfile "$%temp%\test.exe"
section
!define srcroot "c:\myfolder\assets" ;batch file needs to generate a relative path for $instdir
!define filelist "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt"
!tempfile BATCH
!tempfile NSH
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" '@echo off&setlocal&goto main$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" ':StrLen$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'set #=%~2%&set length=0$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" ':stringLengthLoop$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'if defined # (set #=%#:~1%&set /A length += 1&goto stringLengthLoop)$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'set "%~1=%length%"&GOTO :EOF$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" ':writ$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'setlocal&set "d=%~2"$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'echo SetOutPath "$INSTDIR!d:~%rlen%!" >>"%~3"$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'echo File "%~1" >>"%~3"$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'endlocal&endlocal&GOTO :EOF$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" ':main$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'call :StrLen rlen "%~2"$\n'
!appendfile "${BATCH}.cmd" 'for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~1") do call :writ "%%~A" "%%~dpA" "%~3"$\n'
!system '"${BATCH}.cmd" "${filelist}" "${srcroot}" "${NSH}"' = 0
!delfile "${BATCH}.cmd"
!delfile "${BATCH}"
!undef BATCH
!include "${NSH}"
!delfile "${NSH}"
!undef NSH
sectionend
```

Comment: That works ok for my example, but I wanted the process to be automatic as the file list changes.  I realise I could generate the file list directly from NSIS but working with the files in a text file is easier for my situation.

Comment: @fightstarr20: How is this not automatic? (Except for the srcroot part)

Comment: Surely the lines !appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" c:\myfolder\assets\begin.swf$\n would have to change for each new set of files that I need to add?

Comment: My mistake, I have missed out the part of my batch file that generates the file list, sorry!

Comment: The !appendfile "$%temp%\testfilelist.txt" lines would not exists in a real script, sorry if that was not clear...

Comment: I know that your solution is probably the most efficient but as I almost have it working with the batch file Im going to stick to that as time is not on my side with this one.  Thanks for your input though, just wish somebody could fix the batch for me!

Answer (score 2):

This Batch file do what you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INSTDIR=c:\myfolder\assets\
( for /F "delims=" %%a in (files.txt) do (
     set "filePath=%%~DPa"
     set "outPath=!filePath:%INSTDIR%=!"
     if defined outPath set "outPath=\!outPath:~0,-1!"
     echo SetOutPath "$INSTDIR!outPath!"
     echo File "%%a"
  )
) > result.txt
REM move /Y result.txt files.txt
```

First test it and check the result.txt file. If everything is OK, remove the REM part in the last command.

Comment: This batch file works fine for me if I run it directly, but attempting to launch it from NSIS using Excec it fails to generate the result.txt file

Answer (score 2):

I have slightly modified your batch:

```
dir "c:\n\assets" /b /s > "c:\n\original.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=3,4 delims=\" %%G IN (original.txt) DO @echo %%G\%%H| tee -a filelist.txt
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET PATH=C:\n\
set INSTDIR=C:\n\assets\
( for /F "delims=" %%a in (filelist.txt) do (
     set "filePath=%%~DPa"
     set "outPath=!filePath:%INSTDIR%=!"
     if defined outPath set "outPath=\!outPath:~0,-1!"
     echo SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\%%a"
     echo File "!Path!%%a"
  )
) > "c:\n\result.txt"
REM move /Y c:\result.txt files.txt
```